# Getting first element from an query array

Tags: php, mysql, parameter-passing

```
  $post= ('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1 ', array('id' => $_GET['id']),$conn);
$view_path = 'views/single.view.php';
require'views/layout.php';
```

I know that $post variable is an array and if I print_r that on my single.view.php?id=1

I can get result below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [title] =>  title of
            [1] => first post
            [body] =>  body of first  post
            [2] =>  body of first  post
        )

)
```

so on single.view.php if I  write

```
echo $post**[0]**['title'];
```

I can get the title.

however when I try this on my single.php by writing

```
$post= ('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1 ', array('id' => $_GET['id']),$conn)**[0]**;
```

I get

```
Parse error: parse error in /Library/WebServer/www/single.php on line 10
```

which sounds to me like **this is not an array you can't get first of element of it.**.

so my question is how can I get first element of on my $post variable.instead of sending values to single.view.php

Comment: What are those asterisks doing in there?

Comment: just to point out [0]. nothing special.

Comment: what is this [0]; at the end of line 10 ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted *actual* code, not... whatever this is.

Comment: Really funny code. But `$name = $mysqli->fetch_assoc($result)['name']` works fine for me as intended.

Comment: @Jari whats actually funny here ? asking for help ? or learning something new ?

Comment: `$post= ('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1 ', array('id' => $_GET['id']),$conn)**[0]**;` What does this even mean? Makes me sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to PHP 5.4, you cannot directly retrieve an array element from a function:

```
$val = myArray($params)[0]; // wrong
```

However, you can do:

```
$arr = myArray($params);
$val = $arr[0];
```

or

```
$val = current(myArray($params));
```

[current() Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)

Comment: I'm using `PHP 5.4.3` and `$val = myArray($params)[0];` works just perfectly.

Comment: Yes, but obviously the OP is not using PHP 5.4 or it would have worked. I clarified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access arrays like that in versions of PHP < 5.4. You have to do it the long way.

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing

Comment: That upcoming version is 5.4 which is out for some time now ;)

Comment: @PeeHaa - Oh haha i had no clue.